# How to close a window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-graph-api

I know that you can close a window.open with window.close but is there another way. I have a popup that opens facebook connect and i want to shut the popup whenever the user connects to facebook and then refresh the parent window...I thought in the past i used

```
TARGET = "_top"
```

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#signin_menu a').click(function (){
    window.open(
  $('#signin_menu a').attr("href"),
  'mywindow',
  'width=850,height=400'
       );
    return false;
  });
})
```

Also

```
$('#signin_menu a').attr("href")
```

is equal to

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=145554402127660&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://pgp.dev/fb_receive&scope=publish_stream,rsvp_event,offline_access,email,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_events,user_groups,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_online_presence,user_photo_video_tags,user_status,user_website,read_friendlists"
```

So How do i close this popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use close() method of created popup that is returned by the open() method as object:

```
var myPopup;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#signin_menu a').click(function (){

        myPopup = window.open(
            $('#signin_menu a').attr("href"),
            'mywindow',
            'width=850,height=400');

        return false;
    });
})
```

To close do the following:

```
myPopup.close();
```

Comment: There's a small mistake here, which I know is present in the original, but that doesn't mean it can't be fixed - assuming that there are multiple `#signin_menu a` elements, clicking on any of them will open up a popup with it's location set to the `href` value of the **first** `#signin_menu a` element. Using `this.href` would be more appropriate (and faster) here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below

```
window.close();
```